# mysql select query get foreign key against where condition

Tags: mysql

In table [tbl_storytags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XkHv.png) Here, I want `story_id` from the table where `tag_id` in mapped with ***1,8,9,10*** each `story_id`. How can I achieve this?

I am using `SELECT t.story_id FROM tbl_storytags t WHERE t.tag_id IN (1,8,9,10)` where `IN` statement is doing operation of OR but I need intersection result.

```
id  story_id    tag_id  custom_tag
5   1   10  NULL
6   1   11  NULL
7   1   12  NULL
8   1   0   Peace
9   2   7   NULL
10  2   8   NULL
11  2   9   NULL
12  2   10  NULL
13  2   0   Peace
14  4   12  NULL
15  36  7   NULL
16  36  8   NULL
17  36  12  NULL
18  38  9   NULL
19  38  10  NULL
20  38  8   NULL
21  39  0   Lorem Ipsu
22  99  12  NULL
25  101 12  NULL
27  102 1   NULL
28  102 2   NULL
29  102 3   NULL
30  102 4   NULL
31  102 5   NULL
32  102 6   NULL
33  102 7   NULL
34  102 8   NULL
35  102 9   NULL
36  102 10  NULL
37  102 11  NULL
38  102 0   Peace
39  112 0   Peace
40  112 12  NULL
```

Comment: You have pretty much answered yourself in the question. Please add what you have tried and the problem(s) you have encountered.

Comment: Hi, @P.Salmon I have updated the question please see the problem I face

Comment: Indeed IN is shorthand for or.Add code to check that a count distinct of tag_id = 4 where in(1,8,9,10) group by storey_id

Comment: @P.Salmon, `SELECT DISTINCT t.story_id FROM tbl_storytags t where tag_id in(1,8,9,10) GROUP BY story_id;` 
Is there any shorthand AND in mysql or what is the way out to fetch expected rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.story_id 
FROM tbl_storytags t 
WHERE t.tag_id IN (1,8,9,10) 
group by t.story_id having count(distinct t.tag_id) = 4;
```

If no good add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to linked images which we can't